# MySQL syntax Error on create table query?

Tags: mysql, sql

it leads to error in mysql

```
create table book_copies
(
   bookid references book(bookid) on delete set null,  
   programme_id references library_branch(programme_id) on delete set null, 
   no_of_copies int
);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfOOX.png)
a

Comment: The SQL in your image is different from the text of your answer. Please try to use text only.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 1):

You are lacking [types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html) for your columns. Each column needs a type such as `int` or `varchar(255)`.

If your columns are referencing primary keys, their type is probably `int` or `bigint`.

```
create table book_copies (
  bookid int references book(bookid) on delete set null,
  programme_id int references library_branch(programme_id) on delete set null,
  no_of_copies int
)
```

Comment: yes, I got it. how to reference another table thanks!